# Ember.js - Acceptance tests UnrecognizedURLError: /tests

Tags: ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing, ember-cli-mirage

Having recently migrated Ember CLI from 2.15.0 to 3.7.0, the acceptance tests have regressed heavily. Having run the [qunit codemod](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit-codemod), the following issue seems to persist: `UnrecognizedURLError: /tests`.

I have produced a minimum reproduction of the issue via the following acceptance test:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import setupMirage from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support/setup-mirage';


module('Acceptance | poc', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('visiting /poc', async function(assert) {
    await visit('/');

    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
  });
});
```

This results on the three following issues:

```
Promise rejected before "visiting /poc": /tests?filter=poc
Source:     UnrecognizedURLError: /tests?filter=poc
```

```
beforeEach failed on visiting /poc: You must call one of the ember-qunit setupTest(), setupRenderingTest() or setupApplicationTest() methods before calling setupMirage()
Source:     Error: You must call one of the ember-qunit setupTest(), setupRenderingTest() or setupApplicationTest() methods before calling setupMirage()
```

```
Promise rejected after "visiting /poc": Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'destroy' in undefined@ 80 ms
Source:     TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'destroy' in undefined
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does the URL `/poc` exist?

Comment: what version of `@ember/test-helpers` and `ember-qunit` are you?

Comment: @rinoldsimon the test isn't pointing at `/poc` but at the root `/` route

Comment: @mistahenry I'm using `"ember-cli-qunit": "^4.4.0",` and `"@ember/test-helpers": "^1.5.0",`

Comment: Oops, just realised that `ember-cli-qunit` comes with `@ember/test-helpers`.
Removing the independent dev dependancy, the new versions installed are `"ember-cli-qunit@4.4.0"` and `@ember/test-helpers@0.7.27`. Same issue originally posted still persists.

Comment: I would recommend to diff your files against [ember new output](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output) for 3.7.1. This might be related to a configuration option. Maybe it's just missing `ENV.locationType = 'none';` in test environment? Are there any additional or more detailed errors in browser console if running the tests via `http://localhost:4200/tests`?

Comment: @jelhan yeah I have used the new output repo to update `test-helpers.js` and other files. Changing `ENV.locationType = 'history';` to `none` produces some different errors (so that could be progress!). Is `none` the expected value for the acceptance tests?

Comment: `locationType` is set to `none` in test environment for a long time in ember's default blueprint: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/config/environment.js#L35-L36 Actually since `0.1.3` of ember-cli. I would recommend to also compare your runtime configuration for testing environment against ember new output. You might also miss `ENV.autoboot = false` which is required by new testing API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jelhan points to in the comment above, the issue here is missing `test` environment settings within the `environment.js` configuration.

To fix the `UnrecognizedURLError`, adding `ENV.locationType = 'none'` satisfies the requirements of testem.

I also replaced the other environment variables found in the linked [block](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/config/environment.js#L34).

My test environment configuration now looks like this:

```
else if(environment === 'test') {
    ENV.locationType = 'none';
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;
    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.autoboot = false;
  }
```